# Calling printf on two strings in GCC assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am trying to call printf on the _format string but I get an error instead of printing out both of the strings. I was able to get the program to work before adding the _printStr function so I am really unsure of why it won't print out both of them. I can also print out each string separately and it works fine (with 12(%ebp) and 16(%ebp)). This is the code I have:

```
            .text
            .globl      _main
_string:    .ascii      "Hello\0" 
_string2:   .ascii      " World\0" 
_format:    .ascii      "%s %s\0"


_main: // push params, call fn, clear params, return 

            pushl      $_string2 
            pushl      $_string                 
            call      _printStr
            addl       $8, %esp
            ret

//function to print a string passed to it on the stack
_printStr:
            push        %ebp               # save old frame ptr
            movl        %esp, %ebp     # set frame ptr
            pushl       8(%ebp) 
            pushl       12(%ebp) 
            pushl       _format
            call _printf
            addl        $12, %esp          # clear params from stack
            leave
            ret
```

Thanks for your time, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Aren't you pushing your params in the wrong order ?

Comment: Yes, I am mainly concerned with just trying to print both of them out right now though. I updated it, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Your call only forwards the `format` argument to `printf`, not all of them. Due to the format string `printf` ends up treating whatever follows it on the stack as the missing arguments.

Comment: Edited original code to put _format in the _printStr function

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass an unknown string as the first parameter to `printf`. Always use a known format specifier, preferably a literal if possible. If you want to use `printf` to print a string, do something like this:

```
_simpleformat:  .ascii      "%s\0"
```

...

```
                pushl       8(%ebp)
                pushl       _simpleformat
                call _printf
                addl        $8, %esp
```

Comment: Ok thanks for replying, so I need to use the format inside the _printStr function. I edited my original code and it still isn't working, do I have the right idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$` sign in the `pushl _format`. It should read `pushl $_format` because you want to pass its address. Incidentally, you are also passing the two words in reverse order, it will print `" World Hello"`. Also you are missing a line feed, but have an extra space. Finally, putting your string constants in the `.text` section isn't the best practice. See the [fixed version in operation](http://ideone.com/9vEgra) (note I removed some leading underscores that are not needed for ideone, but probably needed on your system)

Comment: Was looking at it the whole time without realizing I forgot the $, thank you. And I did realize it was in the wrong order and fixed that beforehand. It's working now but I am curious, why do you add the line xor %eax, %eax?

Comment: That's to set the value returned from `main` to zero.